# Is there anyway to discover which ip addresses are connected to the db?

Tags: mongodb

I can determine the current number of connections by

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

but all that gives me is the current number of connections. Is there anywhay to determine which ips are connected and which connection number they have been assigned to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From mongo shell run db.currentOp() to show all active connections or db.currentOp(true) to show all connections.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I thought so too until I read this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5085

Comment: This actually does not seem to include inactive connections. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43215754/10474024) however does.

Answer (score 21):

From mongo shell, this will print client IP:port, along with connection ID:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(d){if(d.client)print(d.client, d.connectionId)})
```

**Note**: passing `true` to `db.currentOp()` shows all connections (including idle).  The docs have more examples on filtering connections, see:
[db.currentOp reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) and [currentOp output fileds with descriptions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/currentOp/#currentop-output-fields).

Comment: Thanks, Gary. Perfect answer to the OP question. Thanks especially for the links to the right sections in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your db engine, but one simple way you can do it with netstat, checking the port your database allows to connect, and if you have security concerns you can limit the  ip addresses that connect in the configuration file.  Most databases by default only allow localhost to connect to them.