# MongoDB: Checking number of users using my applications currently which is connected to my MongoDB server.

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to Check the number of users using my applications currently which is connected to  my MongoDB server? Is there any command to find it? Also in the below output 
db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 12, "available" : 807, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(96385) }

the current connection will include the number of users connected to my database through my application? Please explain. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Hello @Ganu, I wanna warn you, even tough your written may contain an example. In generally, application users request from a web server and only the web server accesses to the database server. Just FYI, good luck.

Comment: @user3765109: So that means the web server is a single client, even though many users are using the application @ a given time. Right???

Comment: Yes, you're right. In generally.

Comment: @Ganu Yes. Most of the time web-server becomes the single client that manages the DB.This is for small applications. As the complexity of app grows it may change to multiple webservers or multiple connections from same server. It depends...

Answer (score 2):

`db.serverStatus().connections` shows the **number of connections** made to the MongoDB. But to find the number of users using the DB, you must absolutely know the number of connections a **single client**(user) will open. That means if your application opens 3 connections for single user then you cannot say there are 3 users. You can only say 3 connections are used, so there is only one user.

So you must first define a fixed amount of db connections for a single user.

Remember: unlike MySql, MongoDB is not intended to be directly used with a client. MongoDB is best when used along with a REST server. That means the client first connects to REST server and the DB is handled by the REST server and not the client directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I wanna find any single connection from my application, how to find it? Is it possible to find the IP address of the clients connected to my mongodb server?

Comment: @Ganu I tired this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945107/is-there-anyway-to-discover-which-ip-addresses-are-connected-to-the-db but it didn't work for me. I think you must introduce a web-server as a middle-man between your client and MongoDB. PHP as well as Node.js are good for this job